# Homebrew does not create pip3 symlink on /usr/local/bin

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I installed python3 with homebrew but it does not create symlink to pip3.
When I installed it former, homebrew created pip3 symlink at /usr/local/bin.
But now it does not create.
Note that I know there is a solution I am able to create symlink manually,
But I don't know why homebrew does not create symlink to pip3 despite python formular looks like create symlink. (see [formula of python3 on github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python.rb#L259:L261))

I using:

macOS 10.13.4
python 3.6.5
Homebrew 1.6.6
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision d4c0; last commit 2018-05-26)

Comment: Run `brew info python` and all is explained.