# After installing python3 with Homebrew, Homebrew doesn't create symlink of python in /usr/bin/local

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

### Background

After running `brew install python3` on Mac, I expect there are symbolic of python3 in `/usr/local/bin`, but there aren't.

Checked with `brew info python3`, it shows

```
python has been installed as /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Also, python3 is indeed installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/bin`

Could anyone know how to fix this issue without making links to `/usr/local/bin` manually?

This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549510/homebrew-does-not-create-pip3-symlink-on-usr-local-bin) in SO reported the same issue, but it has no solution.

Also Found an [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/16212) reported.

### Update

After running commands below, it does have correct links in `/usr/local/bin`.

```
brew uninstall python3
brew install python3
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340871/how-to-link-home-brew-python-version-and-set-it-as-default and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454926/homebrew-cannot-link-python Also, I see no reason not to create the link manually.

Comment: Did you try `brew link python3` ?

Comment: I tried `brew link python`, but it does link system wide python to python3. Therefore, I did `brew unlink python@2`, it seems backing to the original. I am just wondering how to make symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` correctly by homebrew itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Overwrite any python 3 brew symlink
brew link --overwrite python3
# Link python3 to python2 using prior symlink to symlink
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```